# The set of points of continuity of a real-valued function on a metric space is a $G_\delta$ set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

> Let $f$ be a real-valued function on a metric space $X$. Show that the set of points at which $f$ is continuous is the intersection of a countable collection of open sets.

I know lots of other properties of continuous function  but in order to prove the above which is applied. any hints are welcomed.

Answer (score 5):

More generally, this is true for functions $f:X\to Y$ where $(X,d)$ and $(Y,d')$ are *any* metric spaces.

**Hint:** For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, consider the sets
$$
U_n:=\{x\in X:\exists\delta>0,y,z\in B(x,\delta)\implies d'(f(y),f(z))<1/n\}.
$$

Comment: These sets are open?

Comment: @user145993 Yes they are. Fix $n$ and $x\in U_n$. By definition of $U_n$, there exists $\delta_x>0$ such that $y,z\in B(x,\delta_x)$ implies $d'(f(y),f(z))<1/n$. Take any $w\in B(x,\delta_x)$ and let $\delta_w:=\delta_x-d(x,w)$. Then $y,z\in B(w,\delta_w)\subseteq B(x,\delta_x)$ implies $d'(f(y),f(z))<1/n$. Hence $B(x,\delta_x)\subseteq U_n$. This shows $U_n$ is open.